# Is there a way to modify existing xlsm file using python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I have an xlsm file and I have come across various methods to modify the file by creating a new file using openpyxl or xlw. Is there any way that I can modify my current file without having to create a new one everytime in the process?

```
from openpyxl import workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'filename', read_only =    False, keep_vba = True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('UI')
wb.save('outfile.xlsm')
```

However, I do not want to create a new file each time I run the code and just want to modify my current file but openpyxl is not compatible with .xlsm type files?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: XLSX files are zip archives and cannot be edited in place.

Answer (score 4):

OpenPyXL 2.6.2 does support xlsm files. Just overwrite your existing workbook.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'filename.xlsm', read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
sheet = wb['UI']
wb.save('filename.xlsm')
```